# When i try to build an executable file with pyinstaller only a .spec file is created, How do i build an executable with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Am using Anaconda prompt, after navigating to the folder where the python code is, i ran the command
pyinstaller --onefile exercise9.py
I noticed that only a file called exercise9.spec was created. i did not see the dist folder where am suppose to find the .exe file as stated by the tutorials am using.

Here is the python code am trying to execute

```
from getpass import getpass
def login():
     username = input("Please enter your username: ")
     password = getpass("Please enter your password: ")
     return [username, password]
try:
    login_details = login()
    if login_details[0] != "admin": 
        raise ValueError()
    elif login_details[1] != "password":
        print("Wrong Password")

    else:
        print("Login successful")
        input("Press enter to exit")
except ValueError:
    print("Wrong User name")
```

Here is the content of the exercise9.spec file

```
block_cipher = None

 a = Analysis(['exercise9.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\schoology\\exer9'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
 pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
 exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='exercise9',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )
```

help me out please i tried with other gui codes i wrote too, but only .spec file is created, am using windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve the issue by navigating to the scripts directory in anaconda prompt and entering this command  :

```
python -m PyInstaller --onefile exercise9.py
```